# Why does Ubuntu 16.04 come with Python 3.5 but not pip3?

Tags: 16.04, python3, pip

This is probably a basic question but I am quite new to Ubuntu. As far as I understand, Ubuntu 16.04 (and the following versions) come with Python 3.5 as default, not Python 2.7.

My question is, why does it not also come with pip3? My assumption at first is that perhaps it's not needed - only people planning on doing some coding will need pip3, not the "general" public.

Is this correct or am I missing something?

Comment: I think that is a purely develper issue and not for the general public.! A regular user won't need it! So your correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Pip3 is merely one click away** in the Software Center, or one shell-command away using apt.

The default install of Ubuntu strives to provide a broad base of applications to a wide variety of users with a small download footprint. It does NOT try to be fully-featured for all corner-cases of all users out-of-the-box -- that is what the Ubuntu repositories are for.